# RxTextView and other widgets not found while using latest com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding:3.0.0-alpha2 library

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-binding

**I wanna use RxJava binding APIs for Android UI widgets in my project.**

Therefore following the guidance as per this site  'https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding'

But I am unable to import any Android UI widgets in my Kotlin File.
**Where as its working fine if I am consuming these widgets in Java File.**
Hence, not been to find the actual of this issue.

For reference following are the gradle file and class files(both kotlin and java) using in same project

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    //RxBinding
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding:3.0.0-alpha2'
}
```

**BindingExample.java class**

[image]

**RxBindingExample.kt class**

[image]

Have tried exploring this issue on S.O. but questions or solutions are available for previous version of lib **'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding'**

Comment: Have you tried to add the same import from the first example manually?

Comment: @LucianoFerruzzi : Yes I tried that as well but showed the same error 'Unresolved reference:RxTextView' at import line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check this reference:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding3/widget/TextViewTextChangeEventObservable.kt

There are different ways to use depending on the language, note the `@file:JvmName("RxTextView")` at the start. If you're using java the class RxTextView is visible, in kotlin you should use the extension functions provided by the lib, `textChangeEvents()` is an example of it.

like that, this will aquire the observable e.g.:

```
val someTextView = TextView(context)
someTextView.textChangeEvents()
```

---

Edit:

Seems that the old class that I've referenced was deleted, here is another one:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding4/widget/TextViewAfterTextChangeEventObservable.kt